# Windows: How to forbid users modifying C

Tags: windows, active-directory, group-policy

In a school we have many Windows 7 client PCs and one 2008 R2 AD.

We have to make sure, that noone can modify the C drive exept the systemadministrators.

Is this possible without any third-party software?

Comment: `We have to make sure, that noone can modify the C drive exept the systemadministrators` - What do you mean "modify"? Make sure the users are standard users and not Administrators and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you mean is to prevent users writing their own data to the C Drive and only having the C Drive for apps - no data.

You can do this through a GPO:
Computer Configuration > Windows Settings > Security Settings > File System: 
In the pane on the right, right-click > Add File > Select the C Drive > Edit Permissions (for Database Security for %SystemDrive%)
Then deploy the GPO to the relevant OU of Computers.